# Hide blocks instead of deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a small slider that switches the preview image to the main image. It works fine now

*blade.php*

```
<div class="custom-carousel">
    @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
    <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        @if($loop->first)
        <span>{{ $article_block_image->title }}</span> @endif
    </div>
    @endforeach @endif @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
    <div class="main-image">
        @if($loop->first)
        <picture>
            <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
            <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
            <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
        </picture>
        @endif
    </div>
    @endforeach @endif
    <div class="img-to-select">
        @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
        <div @if($loop->first) class="img-to-select__item selected" @else class="img-to-select__item" @endif>
            <img src="{{ $article_block_image->preview_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}" data-main-src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" data-mobile-src="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}">
        </div>
        @endforeach @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

*js*

```
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  let mainSrc = $(this).children('img').data('main-src')
  let mobileSrc = $(this).children('img').data('mobile-src')
  let title = $(this).children('img').attr('title')
  let alt = $(this).children('img').attr('alt')
  $('.main-image > picture').html(`
    <source srcset="${mobileSrc}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
    <source srcset="${mainSrc}" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
    <img src="${mainSrc}" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
  `);
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

But now the problem is that when I switch images, all the blocks are deleted, and then they seem to be loaded back, because of which everything on the page twitches and does not work as we would like

Is it possible to do something so that these blocks are loaded immediately and when switching unnecessary ones are hidden, and the necessary ones are shown?

If I add `style="display: none"` then how do I then need to rework the script so that everything is just hidden and shown, and not deleted and reopened

If I use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of `.html()` does it work?

Like so

```
.hide(`
    <source srcset="${mobileSrc}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
    <source srcset="${mainSrc}" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
    <img src="${mainSrc}" alt="${alt}" title="${title}">
  `)
```

and what should be the check condition here at all, when using `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: I don't see a simple change that would achieve this to be honest. This code seems pretty locked in the approach of replacing the HTML on every click. You'd need to take another look at it from the top.

Comment: @apokryfos What are the options then? So that with every click everything is not loaded anew?

Comment: When you render your page load all the images but the ones that should not be selected should have a `style="display: none"` then you can use `.hide()` on the currently visible one and `.show()` on the one you want to show afterwards. I think the loading will be longer since everything will be loaded at the start, but the users probably won't notice because the HTML will load before images and the visible image should be loaded first

Comment: @apokryfos that is, I need to essentially remove `@if($loop->first)` but how should I then do so that the first image is automatically displayed

Comment: Yes you can do `<div class="main-image" style="display: {{ $loop->first ? 'block' : 'none' }}">` but then you will need find the correct image to show in your JS

Comment: @apokryfos I'm sorry, I don't really understand `JS` yet, and I didn't really understand how to hide and show the desired image in my case, can you please explain in a little more detail if you are not comfortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view to this:

```
<div class="custom-carousel">
    @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
    <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        @if($loop->first)
        <span>{{ $article_block_image->title }}</span> @endif
    </div>
    @endforeach @endif @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
    <div class="main-image" style="display: {{ $loop->first?'block':'none'}}">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
            <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
            <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
        </picture>
    </div>
    @endforeach @endif
    <div class="img-to-select">
        @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
        <div @if($loop->first) class="img-to-select__item selected" @else class="img-to-select__item" @endif>
            <img src="{{ $article_block_image->preview_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}" data-main-src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" data-mobile-src="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}">
        </div>
        @endforeach @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your JS you can do:

```
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  let index = $(this).index(); // I think
  $('.main-image').hide();
  $('.main-image').eq(index).show();
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

The idea is to instead of replacing the HTML of the element to find the appropriate element and show it

Comment: everything seems to work, and there are no more flashes and downloads when switching images, thanks a lot for the help)